# Homepage Setting missing

Tags: homepage

Hello I'd like my homepage to be www.abcdxxx.com instead of www.abcdxxx.com/home
But I can't find the Homepage setting in WP customizer to set the home page as a static page. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Same issue. Pages exist and home page is set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It won't appear if you don't have any pages. Make sure you have at least one *published* page created.

Comment: I do have. One hour after I posted the question, the homesetting appeared. It was a mystery...

Comment: Had you published a page in that time? Not having a published page is the only reason that setting wouldn't appear.